# Como criar um Parser em Python?

Tags: python, xml, parser

Para um projeto com manejamento de arquivos, queria converter de "CFG" para "XML", e acredito que em Python não tenha suporte à nenhuma desses dois tipos.

Teve um colega que fez a modificação manualmente, para podermos estudar o XML. Aqui estão as respectivas estruturas CFG e XML:

**CFG:**
http://pastebin.com/404dp2Ny

**XML:** http://pastebin.com/zfwFpqkT

Bom sou meio "intermediário" em Python, mas estou com um problema em COMO vou fazer isso. Li o source do **ConfigParser** e vi que ele usou o módulo **re**, mas como vou usar esse módulo.

Enfim, terei de inventar um parser para ambos? Se não puderem me enviar um código (claro que não podem), mas podem me dizer a ideia a seguir?

---

Eu estava pensando em fazer isso:

Identificar no CFG os tipos de dados, o que é ***Seção*** e o que é ***Dado***.
Criar uma espécie de dicionário temporário com os dados recebidos.
Para então reescrever os dados num arquivo XML de acordo com tipos separados. Criando uma árvore XML.

Comment: O ConfigParser já vai extrair os dados, agora uma duvida, as tags devem seguir exatemente os mesmos nomes das keys no CFG? Ou vc tem um formato especifico de XML?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ConfigParser não compreende este CFG. E o XML é somente um pouco diferente do CFG. Alguns dados não são necessários no XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provavelmente o `ConfigParser` pode ser adaptado para ler o tipo de `CFG` que estás a usar. No entanto, escrever um parser é uma óptima forma de aprender e praticar Python. No meu caso, foi assim que comecei a aprender Python.

## *Como criar um parser em Python?*

É possível fazer isso usando puro Python, sem importar nenhum módulo. Basicamente é um exercício de manipulação de `string`'s. Certamente que há formas mais eficientes de fazer o mesmo, como por exemplo, usando o referido `re` (módulo que lida com regex, [*regular expressions*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express%C3%A3o_regular)).

Continuando com o puro Python, os passos gerais são:

1. Identificar o formato do ficheiro

   - O que separa o parâmetro do valor?
   - Comentários
   - Grupos
   - Casos particulares
2. Definir uma estrutura de dados onde guardar a informação (exemplo)

   - Criar um dicionário em que cada chave é um parâmetro, que guarda um valor
   - Quantos níveis são precisos? Preciso de um dicionário de dicionários?
   - A ordem é importante? Os dicionários não são ordenados. Em alternativa, pode-se usar um [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).
3. Escrever ficheiro ou converter

   - É necessário escrever o ficheiro de volta?
   - Em que formato? Igual ou diferente? (neste caso pretende-se XML)

---

Vamos a isso.

### 1. Identificar o formato do ficheiro

Vendo o [ficheiro de exemplo](http://pastebin.com/404dp2Ny), identificamos o seguinte:

- comentários começam por `#`
- grupos acabam em `:`
- parâmetros e valores estão separados por `=`
- há parâmetros sem grupo, que aparecem primeiro
- assumimos que todos os parâmetros seguintes pertencem a algum grupo
- Atenção: na linha 59 há um comentário que não está identificado: `Game Label Image`; eu coloquei um `#`, mas é possível lidar com estas situações no código

---

### 2. Definir uma estrutura de dados onde guardar a informação

Como temos parâmetros separados por grupos, neste exemplo decidi por uma estrutura do tipo dicionário de dicionários. Exemplo

```
cfg = {
    'grupo 1': {
        'param1': 1,
        'param2': 'abc'
    },
    'grupo 2': {
        'paramA': 'foo',
        'paramB': 123
    }
}
```

Um dos grupos vai ser o `'geral'`, que contém os parâmetros que surgem primeiro, fora de qualquer grupo.

---

### 3. Escrever ficheiro ou converter

Não vou cobrir esta parte na minha resposta, já que o pretendido é converter para XML, e isso já foge à pergunta principal (como criar o parser). Aconselho a leitura do seguinte tópico: [XML to/from a Python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3292973/xml-to-from-a-python-dictionary).

---

## Código

A seguir apresento uma implementação simples que lê um ficheiro segundo os requisitos identificados. Para um desenvolvimento mais complexo, será aconselhado implementar as funcionalidades numa `Class`e.

```
# coding=utf-8

# ficheiro cfg
caminho = '/Users/julio/Downloads/cfg.txt'
# inicializar estrutura de dados
parametros = {}
# criar grupo geral para parâmetros sem grupo
parametros['geral'] = {}
# marcador para saber qual o grupo actual
grupo = 'geral'

with open(caminho, 'r') as cfg:
    for linha in cfg.readlines():
        # apagar espaços em branco no início e fim
        linha = linha.strip()
        # a linha é um comentário ou está vazia, passar à próxima
        if not linha or linha.startswith('#'):
            continue
        # criar grupo
        if linha.endswith(':'):
            grupo = linha.split(':')[0]
            parametros[grupo] = {}
        # criar parametro
        else:
            param, valor = linha.split('=')
            # guardar parametro
            parametros[grupo][param] = valor

print parametros
```

Excerto do output:

```
{'info9': {'color': '#282828', 'attribute': 'Notes', 'width': '250',
           'y': '148', 'x': '290', 'aligned': '0', 'type': 'AttributeText',
           'display': '1'},
 'info8': {'color': '#282828', 'attribute': '#Size', 'y': '148', 'x': '36',
           'aligned': '0', 'type': 'AttributeText', 'display': '1'},
```

Comment: Olhando assim me parece simples, muito obrigado... :D

Comment: @Breno Espero que tenha ajudado. É simples sim, a complexidade vem com a dimensão do problema e o tipo de requisitos. :) Se isto responde à pergunta colocada, considere marcar como resposta aceite ([ver como no tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)).